# Can in line views in oracle sql contain "not in" clause in the query?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, derived-table

For example

```
select *
from t1 
inner join (select * from t2 where t2.id not in (select ID from t2 where city="Paris"))
```

I tried searching Google. There a lot of examples but none of them uses not in. Plus there are no restrictions specified for an in line view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle calls subqueries in the `FROM` clause "inline views".

These are generic `SELECT` queries.  They can contain `NOT IN` with subqueries.  The problem with your query is a lack of `ON` clause and the use of double quotes for a string constant:

```
select *
from t1 inner join
     (select *
      from t2
      where t2.id not in (select ID from t2 where city = 'Paris')
---------------------------------------------------------^ single quotes
     ) t2
     on t1.? = t2.?
-----^ on clause
```

Note:  I would discourage you from using `NOT IN` with subqueries, because they do not work as expected if *any* returned values are `NULL`.  (If that is the case, then no rows are returned.)

I advise using `NOT EXISTS` instead.